# Dynamically Updating Excel Web Part Excel File

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have multiple Excel Web Parts in my SharePoint 2010 site. Each web part is connected to an Excel work book which is generated automatically by a scheduled task on a separate server. Given this, is there a way to automatically map a newly generated excel file to an existing excel web part instead of manually updating them?

I saw a tutorial but it uses the SharePoint dll and other dlls which are found from the SharePoint server itself and as far as I know, I can only execute these items if I have SharePoint installed locally. Is there any way to make it work without having to install SharePoint locally? By the way I was referring to [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms548743%28v=office.14%29.aspx) from MSDN.

**Edit**

I was able to create web parts programmatically using SharePoint.Client.WebParts but I'm having problems creating Excel Web Access Web Parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by using the same concept found in this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee539301%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

All that I needed to do was properly escape quotation marks from the exported web part file in order to map the correct file.